# Spring 4 mvc + security for servlet 2.5 in JBoss5.1.0.GA

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-2.5

I want to use spring 4 with minimal xml configuration for the now new project I am about to develop. I will be using Spring in this project for dependency-injection, mvc, security and jdbc. I will use JOOQ for query generation. (Yes, I need to project to support Postgresql and oracle) (maybe, in future, this app will extended support for REST too). The problem I face now is my production application server is JBoss5.1.0.GA, which obviously does not support servlet 3.0. Now I have a working spring 4 mvc code base with servlet 2.5, but I could not figure out how to configure the security with java config. Because I see most of the examples on spring 4 on servlet 3.0+ versions, and very less not good examples on 2.5. Though I read the spring security from the spring website, it made little difference on implementing it. Have anyone implemented security (db/ldap) on servlet 2.5? Share with me your wisdom and experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security (I suppose version 3.2 as you speak of spring 4) works well on servlet 2.5, at least with xml config. I am not sure that you can use full java config for security, but I am sure annotations can be used for method security.